# Altium PCB Dashed Lines

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I'm using Altium version 22.6 and I am wanting to add dashed lines on my PCB on the "Top Overlay" layer. I've seen plenty of references to dashed lines on versions 21 and before but none post version 21. Is there still an easy way to add dashed lines to a PCB?

Comment: What do those dashed lines represents? And have you tried what you found about dashed lines for version 21? I mean, they might still work

Answer (score 0):

There is not a line style for line objects (in top overlay nor in copper) within Altium Designer for PCB editing.

When editing a schematic, there are drawing tools which include lines, which have a line style where dashed is an option. But this has nothing to do with PCB editing.

To draw a dashed line on the overlay layer, draw a single segment and use of the [paste array](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-dlg-setuppastearraysetup-paste-array-pcb-ad?version=22) function.